# Infinite subintervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem** If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and infinite, then $A$ has at least one accumulation point.

I'll give the proof that the author gives up to the point where I'm confused.

> Let $A$ be a bounded, infinite set of real numbers. Since $A$ is bounded, $A$ is a subset of a closed interval $I_1 = [a_1,b_1]$. Bisect $I_1$ at exactly $\frac{1}{2}(a_1+b_1)$. Note that the closed subsintervals of $I_1$,

> $$[a_1, \frac{1}{2}(a_1+b_1)], \, [\frac{1}{2}(a_1+b_1),b_1]$$

> cannot both contain a finite number of points since $A$ is infinite. This means one of those subintervals contains infinitely many points of $A$.

Couldn't it be the case that both subintervals have infinitely many points? For example, suppose $A=(0,10)$ and let $I_1=[0,10]$. Its subintervals would be $[0,5]$ and $[5,10]$. In this instance, both subintervals have infinitely many points, and we could eventually conclude that $A$ has at least two points of accumulation.

I just wanna make sure that the author isn't insisting that only *one* of the subintervals could have infinitely many points and that it could be the case that both subintervals have infinitely many.

Comment: Yes, both intervals may contain infinitely many points from $A$. But this does not matter for the proof, it is enough that one of them does for sure.

Comment: "This means one of those subintervals contains infinitely many points of $A$"... should be changed to : "*This means* **at least one** *of those subintervals contains infinitely many points of* $A$"

Comment: Note that the proof is that it has "at least one accumulation point"< not "Exactly one"

Comment: The theorem states $at$ $least$ $one$ accumulation point, so the proof $only$ shows that there could not be $none$. E.g. if $A=[0,1]$ then every member of $[0,1]$ is an accumulation point of $A$ but the proof of the B-W theorem does not address that.